# SQL Server 2008 R2 – Track Database Growth (Production Database)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, auto-growth

My requirement is to get the database size information collected daily, I did not find any option to get database growth over a period of time.

Someone please advise what the correct method for this could be.

Comment: There's also the built-in [Performance Data Collector](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677248%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2008 R2 which allows you to collect certain key indicators (including size) of databases and your servers into a performance management database

Comment: @marc_s Thanks alot I was not aware of this at all !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the link which details as creating a table, stored procedure and a SQL Agent job to execute that sp and save details in that table everyday

http://sqljourney.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/sql-server-track-database-size-growth-trend/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can start with this Link : 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176379/determine-sql-server-database-size
2. From this link you will get the CURRENT databases sizes.
3. For getting the DB's sizes per Date or Datetime, you should schedule (create a job) that run the query and insert his results into a table (new table which you should to create for this ).
4. After all these steps you will get a table that holds per date the databases sizes .